# Belgian formats when choosing US language - regional & language settings issue

Tags: 20.04, language-support, system-settings

I have chosen to use English (United States) as system language. I'm in Belgium so I still want to use Belgian formats for dates, numbers and amounts. However, the only choice I have is German Belgian formats which means dates are shown in German in stead of Belgian/English format.

Belgium has 3 official languages (Dutch +-60%, French +-40% and German <1%) -> so it's weird to default to `de_BE` as format ideally it should be `en_BE` or if not possible `nl_BE` or `fr_BE` and all `xx_BE` formats should be possible to choose.

Date is now shown as: **Dez 12** (Dezember is German). I want the date to be shown as **Dec 12** (English format or if not possible then I'd like to use Dutch format for the date).

When searching for *Belg...* formats there is only **Belgien** (German for Belgium) there is no English, Dutch nor French option for Belgian formats

[image: See region & language dialog box]

A workaround is to install extra languages (French and/or Dutch) which requires extra locale software to be installed. In that case it is possible to select French and Dutch language Belgian formats - it's however still not possible to select English-Belgian formats.

[image: region & language dialog when English, Dutch and French languages are installed]

-> remaining issues

1. When just US English is installed -> only German Belgian formats are available to select - others should be selectable and German is not a good default: it should be English, Dutch or French (defaulting to French or Dutch may be politically sensitive in Belgium :-|)
2. Even with English, French and Dutch languages installed, it's still not possible to select English-Belgian formats.

Comment: Generate the locale: `sudo locale-gen fr_BE.UTF-8` and relogin.

Comment: This is a bug that was first reported way back in 2014: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1295627

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical installation does not include regional formats.

1. Go to Settings -> Region & Language -> Manage installed languages -> Install
2. Then: Install/Remove languages -> Dutch. In Regional formats, select Nederlands (België)
3. Logout and login.

Your calendar should be in Dutch.

Comment: thanks oscar - that's indeed a workaround that works - it would be better IMO to have the correct choices for Belgian formats without having to install extra languages - is this a bug - if so, should I create a bug-report somewhere ?

Comment: no idea how to address this, I just listed my workaround

Comment: Hi, I've accepted the answer as it's a workaround that works for me - IMO it would be good to have better defaults in ubuntu and I'm happy to make a ubuntu bug-report/feature request somewhere if someone can guide me to the right place to do it

Comment: thx, although the other answer looks more like what you were after

Answer (score 4):

The locale used for regional formats is determined (aka guessed) by the installer based on the time zone location. Normally that leads to the right thing.

In case of Belgium with multiple important languages there is an ambiguity. I think it picks German simply because it comes first when sorted alphabetically:

```
$ cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED | grep _BE | grep UTF-8
de_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8
li_BE UTF-8
nl_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8
wa_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

To make the installer pick some other language, it would be possible, at least technically, to add `BE` to [this list](https://git.launchpad.net/ubiquity/tree/d-i/patches/localechooser-post-base-installer.patch#n100).

The reason why it's not there already may be political. If you would pick `nl` as the default language, the French speaking folks might be unhappy and vice versa.

Anyway, to have it considered by the developers, you may want to file a ubiquity bug report:

```
ubuntu-bug ubiquity
```

Comment: thx for the clarification

Comment: indeed, it seems de_BE is chosen with this code after no default language is chosen for Belgium    <---->
> grep ' UTF-8' /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED | grep "_BE[.@ ]" | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1
<----->
de_BE.UTF-8
<----->
I'll check out the code a bit more and file a bug/feature request when it's a bit more clear for me which code could be changed

Comment: I've created a bug report for ubiquity here - as en_BE doesn't exist as locale I'm not sure what the best solution would be and I've proposed 3 ways to improve the process in the bug report as the easiest ubiquity solution to set nl as default language for BE might "offend" the 40% of french speaking people : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1907914  -- for most people the workaround should be OK so I've put that answer as accepted answer

Comment: @Koen: Nice. I responded on the bug report.

Comment: The bug was already reported in 2014: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1295627

Answer (score 4):

One way to have the month and weekday names in English is to open the `~/.profile` file for editing and add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

And then relogin.

The `en_DK` locale is not so much a Danish locale, but rather a locale for ISO aware European users who prefer English as the display language.

Comment: Thanks. This really is the part that I was missing.